# Capture devices - Mono c#

Tags: c#, mono, capture, device

I'm looking for a way to list all capture devices (audio and video) with Mono under Linux: microphones, webcam, etc... but I couldn't find anything. Under windows, it's easy doing this with DirectShow, but couldn't find anything like this under Linux.
Of course I could list those devices with a system command line, and parse the string, but before doing this I wanted confirmation that nothing like this exists for Mono.

Thks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

For video, take a look at [V4L](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).  My brief search of Google for Mono bindings did not turn up anything promising, but feel free to [look](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=v4l+mono&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

For audio, most modern Linux distributions will have [PulseAudio](http://www.pulseaudio.org/) installed, which will know about all the audio capture devices in the machine automatically, and which one the user prefers to use at the time.  Again, I don't know of any Mono bindings for this either.